# DAX Statement not returning blanks

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have imported a dataflow from a database into PowerBI. I am trying to write a DAX statement to mimic these constraints on a query I made:

```
SELECT COUNT(IPID) as theSwitches 
FROM MVIEW_E_SWITCH 
WHERE (NORMALPOSITIONA = 0 OR NORMALPOSITIONB = 0 OR NORMALPOSITIONC = 0) 
AND (FEEDERID2 IS NULL)
```

Here is my DAX statement:

```
Open =
( MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONA] = 0
    || MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONB] = 0
    || MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONC] = 0 )
    & ( ISBLANK ( MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2] ) )
```

Dummy Data is below.

```
IPID     NORMALPOSITIONA   NORMALPOSITIONB   NORMALPOSITIONC   FEEDERID2
123141          1                 1                1              GC12
145361          0                 0                1              
096842          0                 0                0              BC32
053912          0                 0                0           
018249          1                 1                1 
827247          0                 1                0              HD32
```

Comment: Can you add some pictures of input and expected output?

Comment: @user8078111 I do not think I am able to add pictures.

Comment: @user8078111 When I add that column in PBI, every result comes back false those and that should not be happening. It is not liking when I add the 'isblank' statement in there.

Comment: Can you at least add dummy data?

Comment: `Open` is a calculated column on the table `MVIEW_E_SWITCH`, right? What data type is `FEEDERID2`?

Comment: @user8078111 I added Dummy Data in the body. `FEEDERID2` is text.

Comment: @collin7681 just to confirm - in the DAX model, `FEEDERID2` has proper `null` values, not just empty strings?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yeah open is a calculated column! `FEEDERID2` is text.

Comment: @stachu I am not necessarily sure. They are blank in the DAX model though.

Comment: And you are counting those values, which satisfies mentioned condition right?

Comment: @user8078111 so I was just thinking about creating a calculated column and flag them as either true or false and only counting the true values in the report section of my pbix.

Comment: What's your expected output for the given data?

Comment: @user8078111 I would be getting a TRUE for two rows . It would be TRUE for IPID 145361 because `NORMALPOSITIONA` and `NORMALPOSITONB` are 0 and `FEEDERID2` is blank, and TRUE for IPID 053912 because `NORMALPOSITIONA` , `NORMALPOSITIONB` , and `NORMALPOSITIONC` are 0 and `FEEDERID2` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

In DAX, `&` denotes string concatenation. Use `&&` for logical AND.

**Edit**: Given that `FEEDERID2` is text, I'm guessing your problem is that you have empty strings `""` instead of true blanks. Instead of  `ISBLANK ( MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2] )` try

```
( ISBLANK ( MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2] ) || MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2] = "" )
```

or

```
LEN ( MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2] ) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still cannot seem to get my DAX Function to match the results of my query.

Comment: OK. From the information provided, I can't tell much else though. Maybe show the full queries for context?

Comment: I edited my original post to contain the whole query! I just need to add a column that is able to satisfy both of those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if it helps mark it as the answer.

Create a calculated column with the following DAX:-

```
Open = IF((Table[NPA] = 0 || Table[NPB] = 0 || Table[NPC] = 0) && ISBLANK(Table[FEEDERID]), TRUE(), FALSE())
```

This should give you the desired output.

P.S. `Column` is to check if the `FEEDERID` is blank or not.

[image: Output]

Comment: Going to check this out now. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: If it works, then mark it as an answer so that others can find it easily.